# Compiling two embedded XSDs: error "Cannot resolve 'schemaLocation' attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am trying to compile 2 embedded XSDs into a single XSD file but I am getting the error "cannot resolve 'schemaLocation' attribute". I am unsure how to fix this but am guessing its the namespaces some how.

Schema1.xsd does an `xsd:include` to Schema2.xsd

**Schem1.xsd (embedded resource) (simplified)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.somedomain.co.uk/application" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.somedomain.co.uk/application" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="Schema2.xsd"/>       
</xsd:schema>
```

**Schema2.xsd (embedded resource) (simplified)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.somedomain.co.uk/application" targetNamespace="http://www.somedomain.co.uk/application" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" id="someId">
</xsd:schema>
```

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            XmlSchema schema1 = null;

            using (XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Example.Schema1.xsd")))
            {
                schema1 = XmlSchema.Read(xtr, new ValidationEventHandler(XSDValidationEventHandler));
                xtr.Close();
            }

            XmlSchema schema2 = null;

            using (XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Example.Schema2.xsd")))
            {
                schema2 = XmlSchema.Read(xtr, new ValidationEventHandler(XSDValidationEventHandler));
                xtr.Close();
            }

            XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();

            schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(XSDValidationEventHandler);
            schemaSet.Add(schema1); //error writes out to console here
            schemaSet.Add(schema2);

            schemaSet.Compile();

            XmlSchema compiledSchema = null;            

            foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())
            {
                compiledSchema = schema;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void XSDValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
        }  
    }
}
```

NOTE: I am not allowed to change the XSDs content or change them to not being an embedded resource.

Any questions feel free to ask

Thanks

Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using embedded files, the default XmlTextReader is not able to find referenced files. After creating the XmlTextReader, you must supply it with a XmlResolver that is aware of handling embedded files.

```
using (XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Example.Schema1.xsd")))
{
  xtr.XmlResolver = new EmbeddedResourceResolver();              
  schema1 = XmlSchema.Read(xtr, new ValidationEventHandler(XSDValidationEventHandler));
            xtr.Close();
}
```

The 'EmbeddedResourceResolver' is not an existing Framework class, but can be created by yourself. You can find a reference implementation below.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

namespace MyApp
{
  public class EmbeddedResourceResolver : XmlUrlResolver
  {
    public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri,
      string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
    {
      Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("the.path.to.your.resource");
    }
  }
}
```

Because you're not allowed to change the XML, your implementation depends on where the embedded resources are put in your project structure.

You can find more info on the XmlResolver [here](http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2009/07/06/xmlurlresolver-using-embedded-xslt-resources-in-c/)

**My final code**

NOTE: For reference both my embedded XSDs were located at the root of my project

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace Example
{
    public class EmbeddedResourceResolver : XmlUrlResolver
    {
        public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, string role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Example.Schema2.xsd");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            XmlSchema schema1 = null;

            using (XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Example.Schema1.xsd")))
            {
                schema1 = XmlSchema.Read(xtr, new ValidationEventHandler(XSDValidationEventHandler));
                xtr.Close();
            }

            XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();

            schemaSet.XmlResolver = new EmbeddedResourceResolver();
            schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(XSDValidationEventHandler);
            schemaSet.Add(schema1);

            schemaSet.Compile();

            XmlSchema compiledSchema = null;

            foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())
            {
                compiledSchema = schema;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void XSDValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
        }
    }
}
```